# How to solve the error "value too large for dtype('float32')?"

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I read many questions similar to this but still can not figure this out.

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_to_predict = array([[  1.37097033e+002,   0.00000000e+000,  -1.82710826e+296,
          1.22703799e+002,   1.37097033e+002,  -2.56391552e+001,
          1.11457878e+002,   1.37097033e+002,  -2.56391552e+001,
          9.81898928e+001,   1.22703799e+002,  -2.45139066e+001,
          9.24341823e+001,   1.11457878e+002,  -1.90236954e+001]])

clf.predict_proba(X_to_predict)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

My issue is neither  `nan` nor `inf` values since:

```
np.isnan(X_to_predict).sum()
Out[147]: 0

np.isinf(X_to_predict).sum()
Out[148]: 0
```

***Question:*** How can I convert `X_to_predict` to values that are not too large for float32 while keeping as many digits after decimal point as possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you inspect the `dtype` of your array `X_to_predict` it should show `float64`.

```
# slightly modified array from the question
X_to_predict = np.array([1.37097033e+002, 0.00000000e+000, -1.82710826e+296,
                         1.22703799e+002, 1.37097033e+002, -2.56391552e+001,
                         1.11457878e+002, 1.37097033e+002, -2.56391552e+001,
                         9.81898928e+001, 1.22703799e+002, -2.45139066e+001]).reshape((3, 4))

print(X_to_predict.dtype)
>>> float64
```

sklearn's RandomForestClassifier silently converts the array to `float32`, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2809) for the origin of the error message.

You can convert it yourself

```
print(X_to_predict.astype(np.float32)))

>>> array([[137.09703 ,   0.      ,       -inf, 122.7038  ],
           [137.09703 , -25.639154, 111.45788 , 137.09703 ],
           [-25.639154,  98.189896, 122.7038  , -24.513906]], 
          dtype=float32)
```

The third value (-1.82710826e+296) becomes `-inf` in float32. The only way around it is to replace your `inf` values with the maximum of float32. You will lose some precision, as far as I know there is currently no parameter or workaround, except for changing the implementation in sklearn and recompiling it.

If you use `np.nan_to_num` your array should look like this:

```
new_X = np.nan_to_num(X_to_predict.astype(np.float32))
print(new_X)

>>> array([[ 1.3709703e+02,  0.0000000e+00, -3.4028235e+38,  1.2270380e+02],
           [ 1.3709703e+02, -2.5639154e+01,  1.1145788e+02,  1.3709703e+02],
           [-2.5639154e+01,  9.8189896e+01,  1.2270380e+02, -2.4513906e+01]],
          dtype=float32)
```

which should be accepted by your classifier.

---

**Complete code**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                             random_state=42)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

X_to_predict = np.array([1.37097033e+002, 0.00000000e+000, -1.82710826e+296,
                         1.22703799e+002, 1.37097033e+002, -2.56391552e+001,
                         1.11457878e+002, 1.37097033e+002, -2.56391552e+001,
                         9.81898928e+001, 1.22703799e+002, -2.45139066e+001]).reshape((3, 4))

print(X_to_predict.dtype)

print(X_to_predict.astype(np.float32))

new_X = np.nan_to_num(X_to_predict.astype(np.float32))

print(new_X)

#should return array([2, 2, 0])
print(clf.predict(new_X))



# should crash
clf.predict(X_to_predict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is quite misleading at times. if you have blank values in the data set ( which means certain features in the dataset have blank values)even then you can get this type of error. How do we resolve this ...

Covert the dataframe and export them into csv. below is the code "df" is the dataframe Dataframe to CSV
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',archive_name='out.csv')
df.to_csv('out.zip', index=False, compression=compression_opts) You can also try this

df[df['column_name'] == ''].index

Identify the features which have blank values by analyzing the output CSV.

Remove the complete record which have blank values, through the below code df = df.dropna(subset=['column_name'])