# ValueError: Input contains a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, random-forest

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset=pd.read_csv('/content/train.csv')
data=pd.DataFrame(dataset)
index_names = data[ data['LotFrontage'] == "NA" ].index
data.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
X=data.iloc[0:200,[0,3,4,17,18]].values
Y=data.iloc[0:200,[80]].values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, 
Y, test_size= 0.25, random_state=0)
sc_x= StandardScaler()
x_train= sc_x.fit_transform(x_train) 
x_test= sc_x.transform(x_test) 
classifier= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= 200,criterion="entropy")  
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

[classifier.fit(x_train, y_train) This syntax is showing below error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1br9.png)

and for
`np.isnan(x_train.values)`  //result : false
np.isinfinite(x_train.values)   //result : false

Comment: it will be helpful, if a sample mock dataset is provided for reference

Answer (score -1):

Took me 10 seconds to find a [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894904/how-to-solve-the-error-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32)...

Anyhow, RandomForestClassifier masks your data as float32's, your original is probably a float64, and therefore you get a size error as information is lost.
Float32s should do the job fine though, so you can easily cast your data to a float32:

```py
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train).astype('float32')
y_train = sc_x.fit_transform(y_train).astype('float32')
```